# Refresh listview database

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, listview

I'm new to Android studio and i want to make a 2-tabs app that saves data from one tab into a database, and then displays the database on the second tab on a listview.

The problem is that it does not refresh automatically and i have to exit the app and launch it back to see the new data on the second tab. What is the solution?

The DatabaseHelper class :

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HISTORY.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "history_table";
    public static final String COL1= "SUM";



    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL1 + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1, item);

        Log.d("DatabaseHelper", "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);


        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }

    }

    public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return data;
    }
}
```

The second tab fragment:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.scratch.DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class History extends Fragment {



    private ListView mListView;
    private DatabaseHelper db=null;
    private Cursor constantsCursor=null;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;


    public History() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        View histv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

        mListView = (ListView) histv.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        Log.d("ListDataActivity", "populateListView: Displaying data in listview.");

        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        if (data.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "EMPTY DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                listData.add(data.getString(1));
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);

                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        return histv;
    }


}
```

Comment: Access your database in onResume, that way every time the screen reappears, the data in your table should refresh

Comment: Can you be more specific where do i implement it?

Comment: Nevermind, i got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) to store data and [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) to observe the changes. It will help you in all the scenarios without re-launching the app.

According to your need you can save data in first tab to fetch and observe the changes in another tab.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24765135)

Comment: Thank you for reviewing regarding the question it has mentioned the older approach which may or may not be applicable at present. I have provided the links to official android documentation which describes the solution of the problem mentioned in the query. Otherwise I would have provided full solution.